# Which languages are supported by django as part I18N, Localization

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to do Internationalization using Django. I've followed through docs and able to set it up right.

My questions here are

i) What are all the language supported by django?

ii) I've created '.po', '.mo' message files for the languages 'de' , 'de-at' but when trying to access those resources from API I'm only able to get resources from 'de' for both the cases. Does Django overrides 'de-at' by 'de' message file resources. Why is it so?

I've created message files using below commands by executing in project directory.

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l de
```

After running above command. I've added resources for both the languages corresponding in their '.po' file

```
django-admin.py compilemessages
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you add your languages in your settings as well as middleware ?

Comment: No. I didn't added any languages in my settings file and it is working fine for some languages. I've tried with japanese(ja), It is working fine even without adding languages in my settings file.

Comment: Did you try using the format `de_AT`, that the django documentation says you should use?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/#definitions

Comment: @HåkenLid I've just tried with de_AT. Even after using this also not returning proper resource messages. It is failing to load de_AT resource file, as a next option It is showing en-us as base language response as I've configuration with " LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us' "

Comment: Does it work if you add all the language you want to support to `LANGUAGES` in the settings?

Comment: No It didn't worked. After adding languages in my settings file, It is not even working for the languages which was working previously.

The code used to add languages in settings file

from django.utils.translation import ugettext

ugettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
  ('de', ugettext('German')),
  ('en', ugettext('English')),
  ('pt-BR',ugettext('Brazilian Portuguese'))
)

Answer (score 0):

de-at is not supported by Django. So by default Django takes de message files.

Django documentation says :

In each of these places, the language preference is expected to be in the standard language format, as a string. For example, Brazilian Portuguese is pt-br.

If a base language is available but the sublanguage specified is not, Django uses the base language. For example, if a user specifies de-at (Austrian German) but Django only has de available, Django uses de.

Hence It returns messages inside a file 'de'

Answer (score 0):

If the question is actual this might help you.

I had task to translate website both to de and de-at.
Django supports de-at language.
List of supported languages:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052(v=vs.85).aspx
Or you can find on git language_info, I saw list of supported languages there too.
If you created in languages de-at - dash is separator and folder in locale named de_AT ( makemessages de_AT) it is enough. Django defines them as different languages. Problem may be in form you are using on front-end side. In my case form that I got from django documentation crashes on sublanguages so try to change your front-end form, you can find them in another stackoverflow questions.